# Preconfigured Rails Development Virtual Machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, virtual-machine, development-environment

All,

Does anyone know of a preconfigured Linux-based virtual machine I can use as a Ruby on Rails development environment? My laptop runs Windows 8.1, which is not an ideal platform for Rails development and is not used by professional Rails developers.

What I'm specifically looking for is an off-the-shelf Ubuntu VM image I can download and run inside VMWare Player for Windows. The image would already have Ruby and Rails installed and come pre-configured with some common gems like RSpec and Capybara. This way, I don't have to install Ubuntu and all my development tools from scratch.

I already tried the VM image that is used in UC Berkeley's free online Rails-based software engineering course (BerkeleyX CS-169.1x), which can be found at:

https://courses.edx.org/courses/BerkeleyX/CS-169.1x/2013_Summer/wiki/CS169.1x/illustrated-vm-install/.

Unfortunately, this image uses Oracle VirtualBox, which did not jive well with my Windows installation and screwed up my power settings and sleep mode badly.

Just to clarify, I'm not looking for a VM to host and deploy production Rails apps in (i.e., Amazon AWS/Cloud Services). I'm just looking for a VM to develop in, with access to the Linux terminal and the Rails command line.

Comment: Installing RoR is relatively trivial, once you choose between RVM and RBEnv. Development tools is a whole 'nother ball game, Mine is VIM with extensions for instance. Plenty of tutorials about for setting up a Rails dev environment, you could have done it by now. :(

Comment: Bitnami Ruby Stack: https://bitnami.com/stack/ruby

Answer (score 0):

You do need a vm. Period. Developing Rails on any type of windows based environment is foolish. You can certainly do your coding there (while running it on a nix box), but Rails is built to be run on a server, virtually no one runs a windows based server for Rails for precisely the reasons you are running into.

By far the easiest method to do that is through services such as https://c9.io/ or https://www.nitrous.io. They give you a box to work off of for free.

My other suggestion is actually a bit different. Don't. By that I mean don't use a preconfigured box. If you are in the beginning phases using one of the virtual VM's, but if you know you want to get deeper with Rails having gone through the process of setting up a box and install rails on it is both instructive and not as difficult as you might think. I could post a list of instructions here but they would fairly quickly become obsolete. Everything changes including Rails and you will need the skill-set of updating and installing thinks in a nix environment to survive with Rails or web development as a whole. I assure you it isn't as hard as it sounds.

Answer (score -3):

Don't get a VM, you don't need it

Windows 8.1 works fine with Rails - just use something like [RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/en) to install Ruby & Rails, and then you'll be able to install as many gems as you want

Comment: Rich, thanks for your answer. I recently tried deploying a sample Rails app to Heroku from the Windows command-line using Git, and I got all kinds of cryptic error messages about gem version incompatibilities and dependencies. I spent an entire day troubleshooting with the help of a seasoned Rails veteran and he concluded that the problem lied with Windows and its implementation of Rails.

Comment: To follow up on my last comment, as I understand it, Rails was not meant to be run within Windows and most companies use either Mac OS X or Linux as their Rails development platform. I'm hoping to land a job as a Rails dev, so I need to learn how things are done in  "the real world", so to speak.

Comment: Hey buddy, you're right in that most co's use Linux or Mac OSX to develop Rails; only for compatibility. Rails is designed to run on Ruby - which means you just need to make sure you have the Ruby environment & dependencies sorted out to make it work. It's less about environment & more about learning how the stack operates

Comment: Got any specific error messages which appear when you `bundle install`?

Comment: I think it's highly optimistic to say you can develop rails on Windows. I'd nearly give this a -1, as things like git not understanding capital letters (and not great in other areas) as well as gems you are highly likely to use not supporting windows, a VM makes the most sense.

Comment: We develop on Windows because we use Photoshop & other graphics packages. It's a pain to install *some* gems, but nothing you can't overcome. I'd highly recommend Windows as a dev environment :)

Comment: Recently tried railsinstaller.org myself.  Although it appears to work great on first load, I had numerous issues once I got started with gem versions, couldn't get the local server started, etc... I recommend a VM for sure.